# Extend Regular Expression to allow hyphen

Tags: regex

How do I extend this regular expression to allow -(hyphen), when I add escape (`\-`) I am getting an error 'unrecognized escape sequence'.

```
[RegularExpression("[0-9A-Za-z- ]*", ErrorMessage = "Not a valid username")]
```

Comment: Doesn't regex you provided allow hyphens? Also you would want to add `^` in the beginning and `$` in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
@"[0-9A-Za-z \-]*"
```

Comment: You might just need the "@" in front to allow putting the "\" in your quoted string. Like you have to do when entering paths (filenames).

Answer (score 0):

A `-` in the middle of a character class is a character range. To include the character `-` itself, put it at the start or end of a class, like `[-A-Za-z0-9 ]`.